# How to use cluetip with backbonejs

Tags: backbone.js, cluetip

Is there any example code showing use of cluetip with backboneJS? on click of button i want to show a cluetip popup. But I found no example for this.

Comment: backbone doesn't change the way you use this plugin

Comment: any example of backbone with cluetip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backbone shouldn't change how you use cluetip here is the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/ravikumaranantha/zfcEd/1/)

HTML

```
<script type="text/template" id="template1">
    <p> <a id = "houdini"
    href = "houdini.html"
    title = "|Houdini was an escape artist.|He was also adept at prestidigitation." > Houdini </a></p>
</script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

JavaScript

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({

    render: function () {
        this.$el.html($('#template1').html());
        this.$('#houdini').cluetip({
            splitTitle: '|', 
            showTitle: false 
        });
    }
})


var view = new MyView({
    el: '#container'
})

view.render();
```

Comment: is it possible to use .tpl for href?

Comment: if i try to use local div then it affects my router and cluetip is not displayed any solution for using local div for cluetip??

Comment: you comment doesn't convey the problem very clearly, please try providing more info, I shall suggest you a solution

Comment: what if i have a div which is hidden on the same page and i dont want to create separate html file for may cluetip content. If i provide id  of my hiddent div to href then it affects my router and page is redirected to a different url. It would be a great help if you can provide me example of using local div as cluetip content on click of button.

Comment: provide me a example of same working without backbone, I shall help you out to execute the same in backbone

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zfcEd/3/ i am using this but alert of button is not displayed. can u please help me on this??

Comment: Hi @PriyaBhatt #button is not being rendered inside view, i mean `#container` cluetip uses different DOM elements to render tips, which  gets appended to body. Here is updated jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ravikumaranantha/zfcEd/4/

Comment: thanks so much for your help. So if i want to add click event of button inside popup i need to use jquery's click event right?.  Is it possible to use backbone's event for #button's click in this example??

Comment: nopes, reason being, backbone events hash let you add events on elements within view.